# How to force Swift to recognize apostrophe?

Tags: swift, string, string-formatting, swift-string

I am trying to replace all apostrophe (') characters in a string with another character.
I am running this code:

```
someString.replacingOccurrences(of: apost, with: "a")
```

I have tried to let *apost* equal the following:

```
apost = "\'"
apost = #"'"#
apost = "'"
```

None of them have removed the apostrophe from someString.

Please let me know if there is a way to get Swift to replace apostrophe's.
Thank you.

Comment: The last one should work. Can you show the string input? Maybe it's a full width apostrophe?

Comment: I'd print the original string. There are many characters looking quite similar to an apostrophe. Like ‘this’. No apostrophe here.

Comment: wellingtons' is the input string. I am typing the same apostrophe from my keyboard into the code and into the input string.

Answer (score 2):

The `replacingOccurrences(...)` method returns a *new* string object with the apostrophes replaced. The original `someString` object isn't changed by this. You need:

```
someString = someString.replacingOccurences(...)
```

If that's what's happened, turn more warnings on in Xcode (or look at the warnings). On my setup, this wouldn't have compiled because of the unused return value.

Comment: I understand this, my original code sets a new string equal to replacingOccurences. That new string does not have the apostrophe removed.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. It's because the apostrophe is not the right character; it should be a typographic (or “curly”) apostrophe (`’`), not a typewriter (or “straight”) apostrophe (`'`). Copy and paste the code below, or just the correct apostrophe character:

```
searchQuery = searchQuery.replacingOccurrences(of: "’", with: "")
```

Comment: This is effectively the same as [Mark’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68431775/3025856) from a couple of months ago. The only difference is that you chose to use the literal character instead of the encoded character. But it’s functionally identical.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with it not recognizing apostrophies or single quotes. To find and replace them, use the unicode for each character.
This worked for me.

```
let str = "mark's new name is 'mike'"

// apostrophe
var modstr = str.replacingOccurences(of: "\u{0027"}, with "")

// left single quote
modstr = modstr.replacingOccurences(of: "\u{2018"}, with "") 

// right single quote
modstr = modstr.replacingOccurences(of: "\u{2019"}, with "") 

// output
print(modstr)
```

Output:

```
marks new name is mike
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a comparison character for apostrophe as
char charToCompare = (char)8217;